# How to get methods return to print average?

Tags: java

I am assigned to make a grade calculator using java methods. I am trying to get the average of the scores to print but the only printing of the letter grade should occur in the method, Course. How do I store the return value holding the average so I can put it into an if else statement to determine a grade?

```
enter code here
public class calculator {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Course(60, 10, 80);
    Course(50, 40, 30);
}

public static void Course(double score1, double score2, double score3) {

}
public static double Score(double score1, double score2, double score3) {
    return average(score1 + score2 + score3) / 3.0;
}
```

Comment: Your asking how to set a variable to a value?

Answer (score 1):

This answer consists of hints for you to solve the problem yourself.  It is not in your best interests for us to just fix your code for you.  (You won't **learn** to program that way ...)

It looks like you are *trying* to declare a constructor here.  But constructor does not have a `void` return type, and cannot be declared as `static`.

```
public static void Course(double score1, double score2, double score3) {

}
```

It looks like you are trying to declare a method to compute and return an average.  If so, you have the method name incorrect.  (It should be `average` I would think ...)  And your formula for computing an average should *just* add the 3 numbers and divide by 3.  (And if the (ahem) `Score` method is supposed to do something else, then that's not the way that you would call an `average` method.)

```
public static double Score(double score1, double score2, double score3) {
    return average(score1 + score2 + score3) / 3.0;
}
```

---

> How do I store the return value holding the average so I can put it into an if else statement to determine a grade?

You can declare a variable and assign a value to it; e.g.

```
double something = computeSomething(/* some arguments */);
```

Comment: the public static void line was the original line given by the professor in the assignment doc he told us the method header should be that line. I have also tried assigning the value by using double average =Score( score1 ,score2 ,score3); in the course method then I attempted to write return(60+10+80)/3 under public static double but when I run it nothing prints

Comment: Of course nothing prints.  You don't have a print statement.

Comment: I got the average to print , but I am confused do I need to declare another variable to store the average of the other set of numbers from the course main method or is there a way to combine them and store them both in the same variable so I won't be making separate if else statements. The next part is to connect it to an if else statement that gives a letter grade and also checks if any of the scores are below 50 in the main method it prints automatic fail